# Create a form with input controls dynamically from JSON using Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, typescript, dynamicform

I need to create a form with controls dynamically from JSON using Angular 2.0.

I'm very new to Angular 2.0 and Typescript. I'm totally clueless, where to start with the development.

Any help is much appreciated.

Below is the sample JSON

```
"General": {
        "None": [
            {
                "FieldName": "100",
                "DisplayName": "Mapping Name",
                "ClassSize": "col-sm-6 col-xs-12",
                "Field": [
                    {
                        "ControlType": "TextBox",
                        "FieldClass": "col-sm-6 col-xs-12",
                        "Required": "True",
                        "MaxLength": "10",
                        "RegularExpression": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "FieldName": "101",
                "DisplayName": "Select Target File Type",
                "ClassSize": "col-sm-6 col-xs-12",
                "Field": [
                    {
                        "ControlType": "Dropdown",
                        "FieldClass": "col-sm-6 col-xs-12",
                        "Required": "True",
                        "Options": [
                            {
                                "Description": "--Please select--",
                                "ID": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "Description": "Row Per Day",
                                "ID": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "Description": "Row Per Week",
                                "ID": 2
                            },
                            {
                                "Description": "Row Per Transaction",
                                "ID": 3
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Have you seen this guide? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @yurzui: I tried the example which was mentioned in  angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html and I was able to create the UI by parsing my JSON. But I need some controls to be in the same row rather than displaying it in separate row. Since the example uses switch statement for displaying my controls I'm not sure about acheiving my requirement. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Create dynamic form group and loop through the json and create respective element, where forms input type and its related attributes(like name, value, placeholder,type,required,pattern etc) were varying as per resource's attributes. So render the forms at run time.

Reference information

[Creating forms in angular 2 using json schema at run time](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Creating-forms-in-angular-2-using-json-schema-at-run-time)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import a FormBuilder from @angular/forms. Then create a FormGroup.

```
public form: FormGroup;

private _buildForm() {
  let obj = {};
  General['None'].forEach(val => {
    obj[val.fieldname] = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  });

  _fb.group(obj);

}
```

On the template you will need loop through the form controls and and create the form based on the type.

This answer may not be give you all  the answers you need but it's an eye opener on what you can do.

You may want to use FormArrays depending on how you'd want to implement.

Read through the angular2 documentation on forms. Also watch this video.

[Angular 2 Forms | Kara Erickson - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYv9lsrV0s4)

[Forms - ts - GUIDE - Angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)

Comment: The JSON which I receive will be more dynamic and I don't know the root elements which will be included in that file.

Comment: You need to have a consistent kind of data for the method stated above to work. You may as well manipulate the data and make them form a specific pattern.